# Is it possible to override the relative path ~/ throughout my web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, asp.net-4.0

**Back Story**
I am currently updating an existing web application to support a multi-tenant environment.  Today we current host an application on http://www.example.com/MyApp, but now we must be able to support multiple clients on the same web application.

So each client should be able to access the application through urls like:
http://www.example.com/MyApp/Client1
http://www.example.com/MyApp/Client2

The web application is an ASP.NET webforms app that we are also upgrading to use .NET 4.  I have already implemented the new routing available in ASP.NET 4, and I haven already put the appropriate routes in place to support the multi-tenant architecture.

The example URL http://www.example.com/MyApp/Client1/SomeModule/SomePage.aspx will route to and execute `/MyApp/SomeModule/SomePage.aspx` and I have access to the client part from within the RouteData.

BUT...

**Main Question:**
We have links in many parts of the application that use url's like `~/SomeModule/SomePage.aspx`, so when they render out to the browser they will still show `/MyApp/SomeModule/SomePage.aspx`, but what I really want is to have it contain one of my route values to inject the client page like `MyApp/Client1/SomeModule/SomePage.aspsx`

Is there a way to override what the `~/` means throughout my application without going through my entire app and updating the links?

Comment: Its an interesting and relevant problem when using routing or url-rewriting.

Comment: @Wallace Breza have you completed the above task if yes can you share me those ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doesn't seem like overriding the `~/` is possible.  We have decided to take a different approach and create utility methods to help manage links and paths within our multi-tenant environment.

The best option I saw to actually accomplish this is to implement `IUrlResolutionService`, but we were unable to make this work successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `AppRelativeVirtualPath` property on your Page object to your desired path. But you have to do it as the first thing after your handler is created, since every control added to your `Controls`-collection will inherit this value from its parent.

A way to do this is to subclass the `PageHandlerFactory` class which is responsible for creating a `Page` instance when your request a .aspx file. Override the `GetHandler` with the following code:

```
public override IHttpHandler GetHandler(HttpContext context, string requestType, string virtualPath, string path)
{
    var handler = (Page)base.GetHandlerHelper(context, requestType, VirtualPath.CreateNonRelative(virtualPath), path);
    page.AppRelativeVirtualPath = "...";

    return page;
}
```

and of course change the registration under httpHandlers in your web.config to point to your new factory class.

Comment: I tried this out, but changing the AppRelativeVirtualPath doesn't seem to affect url's within controls (such as HyperLink) on my page.